# Cache Results of Db queries and Keep them updated

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, caching

My usecase is

1. I want to cache results of few database queries in memory so that when same query is repeated again, results can be returned from memory.
2. Data can get modified at source DBs. In that case, I want Cache/Query Results to get reflected with changes in data on source
3. I want to design a system in generic way so that users can configure queries etc.

My question is that is there  any framework/tool provides this kind of functionality?

Hibernate etc support caching but their usage is justified only for rarely changed objects. 
They are not good at caching Objects which are more prone to changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to look at the [query cache](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) support.

Comment: The OP wants automatic cache eviction when a row in the database is updated, which is more than just query cache. As far as I know, this is a rarerly observed thing. ASP .NET has the SqlCacheDependency, but for Java, the options seem slim.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Hibernate Dynamic SQL Cache](https://github.com/mrniko/hibernate-dsc) module